# D3: Why is d3.format(".2s") formatting -0.5 as -500m?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have a d3 scale. The tick values are fixed at [0, -0.5, -1]. With the tick format set to ".2s" the value -0.5 is displayed as -500m. Without the tick format set, the value is displayed correctly.

[image: with fomat]

[image: without format]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Formatting function works as properly in your case. `format(".2s")` it means "SI-prefix with two significant digits" - from [docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-format). There is awesome demo-page when you can choose formatting function for you - http://bl.ocks.org/zanarmstrong/05c1e95bf7aa16c4768e

Comment: The thing is. I'm using that tick format to display (for example) 350,000 as 350k. Why is -0.5 equal to -500m? I assume that 'm' stands for millions?

Comment: You are welcome. `m` stands for "milli", for millions (or "mega") used `M`. You can see description for all prefixes of numbers here - https://github.com/d3/d3-format#locale_formatPrefix

Comment: @WilliamMoore You can see my answer. 500m is preferred over 0.5 for the International System of Units.

Answer (score 1):

According to the documentation at https://github.com/d3/d3-format the format you've chosen is defined as:

> `d3.format(".2s")(42e6);   // SI-prefix with two significant digits, "42M"`

[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_prefix) states the preference of International System of Units:

> Prefixes corresponding to an integer power of one thousand are generally preferred. Hence 100 m is preferred over 1 hm (hectometre) or 10 dam (decametres)...

Thus, .5 in the format you've chosen comes to 500m which is preferred display for the format.

Answer (score 1):

Lowercase "m" is `milli` or `10^-3`:

```js
console.log(500 * Math.pow(10, -3))
```